# UIView Animation animates position but not width

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to transform a UISearchBar, like in Mobile Safari: touch in the search field and it grows while the location field shrinks.

My current animation to alter the width and position of the search field only animates the position: just before it slides to the right place, it simply snaps out to the right width. Here's my code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"searchGrowUp" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

CGFloat findFieldWidth = findField.frame.size.width;
CGFloat urlFieldWidth = urlField.frame.size.width;
CGRect findFieldFrame = findField.frame;
CGRect urlFieldFrame = urlField.frame;

findFieldFrame.origin.x = findFieldFrame.origin.x - 150.0f;
findFieldFrame.size.width = findFieldWidth + 150.0f;
urlFieldFrame.size.width = urlFieldWidth - 150.0f;

urlField.frame = urlFieldFrame;
findField.frame = findFieldFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I've modified this code slightly for the sake of presenting it here, but I hope this gives the gist.

Any guesses as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Aaron.

Comment: This better not be for Macinsite! :>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this post: [Changing the size of the UISearchBar TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield/588941#588941)

Turns out the contents of a UISearchBar don't resize properly along with the outer layer. So you have to call -layoutSubviews: within the animation block after the frame is set on the searchbar. So the block ends like:

```
[findField setFrame:CGRectMake(findField.bounds.origin.y, findField.bounds.origin.y, findFieldWidth, findField.bounds.size.height)];
[findField layoutSubviews];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Props to Nick Farina!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when trying to animate the width of a `UISearchBar`.

On iOS 4 and later, I found that using `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` as an option for

```
+[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works but according to Apple docs you *"should not call this method"*. The clean solution is to use `layoutIfNeeded` method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                      delay:0.f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

    [searchBar setFrame: ...
    [searchBar layoutIfNeeded];

    ...
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a bit old, but I was running into a similar problem.
I didn't want to use layoutSubviews because the documentation says you shouldn't call that method directly.

What I did to solve my problem was call **sizeToFit** on the subview within the animation block.

Comment: I had the same problem with a UITextView.  This is the only answer that solved the problem for me.