# Setting the frame of the section index for a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, indexing

Short question, I've been googleing around but cannot come up with a solution. I have a working UITableView with an index on the right side. At the top of the table I have a search field of approx. 44 px in height, placed in the first table cell. Unfortunately the section index shows over the search field, which looks a bit odd. Also, one cannot press the (X) button to erase input because the index is shown over it. Is there a way to lower the index so that the first cell is visible, without index overlap?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Reinder

Comment: Are you after the same behaviour as Apple's Contacts app? Are you using UISearchDisplayController to manage the search?

Comment: Would the stuff in the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616860/uitableview-section-index-overlaps-search-bar help?

Comment: It's a UISearchBar with delegate protocol. However, I think that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work in my case. I already have a navigation bar, in another view, above it. Don't need another. Isn't there a way to set the index frame?

Comment: Not totally, the first question is relevant, plus if you use UISearchBar you'll have some work to do possibly (see the answer linked below), but if you use the search display controller it should handle things (and more) for you.