# UISearchBar: how can I stop it resizing when clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` (with `UISearchDisplayController`) as title view of `UINavigationBar`. There are also two buttons on either side of the searchbar within the navbar.

When clicking on `UISearchBar`, it becomes wider and covers the button on the right of it.

How can I stop it from becoming wider?

Things tried but didn't work -->

- The widened search bar then becomes the original size if the device is rotated.
  So, tried calling `[searchBar setNeedsLayout]` in -`searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`
- All different `auto-resizing mask` options in `IB`

Edit: Didn't mention, but this is on iPhone (as we can put `searchbar` inside toolbar in iPad..)

Comment: Possible duplicate and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006209/uisearchbar-animation-hidding-button

Comment: @CollinPrice Unfortunately, answer in the link you mentioned doesn't work. :(  Adding [self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0)]; for example in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar method did nothing...

Comment: seem to trigger with searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch: but it still widens a little - must be the auto-sizing of the title view.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, taking hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield) if the search bar is put in UIView of desired size then this is set as title view of NavBar, it doesn't go wider !

But... Since you can't make cancel button to show/not show as you wish, I realized it's not so useful.
(As seen in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496310/hide-uisearchbar-cancel-button) etc)

Comment: Yeah, I think we just have to contain the UISearchBar inside a UIView with our desired width.. @s-t

Comment: This is so smart - thanks a million. Just helped me out!