# How can adjust search bar size of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using UISearchDisplayController using nib file.But in that when I am going to search at that time search bar frame's size automatically resize as view's size.I have made changes with its contentStretch ,frame ,and also try to made other changes but could not fix it's size.So if you have any suggestion for it  so please tell me.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield

Comment: @Sarah Friend i know it is same type of question as describes there.But My  question is other.It make adjust size of table only and I have no issue with it.I want to adjust size of search bar which one resize automatically and not getting it's actual size which i have made.

Comment: not getting you. Can you explain with some screen shot or something. I am afraid your question will be closed soon..!!

Comment: @Sarah I have attached my screen shot.

Comment: @sarah The duplicate you point to answers a subtlety different question.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it right now using this method.

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 352, 44);
}
```

But I am not satisfied with this.So please if is there any other option then please suggest too.

Thanks friends.

Comment: Sadly there is not much else you can do. Changing the size works but the animation is horrible. The best you can do is to create your own version of UISearchDisplayController