# searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch not resizing searchbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Just wondering why and need to solve it. i have this searchbar looks like this.
[image]

which clicked will move up to the top and expend to 0,0,320,searchbar's height.

[image]

which clicked Cancel, it should resize back to 33,55,270, searchbar's height. but it doesn't

[image]

the searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch will work to resize back, however there is a 1 sec lag that user could see the changes. any body why in searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch the animation resize wound't work ?.

thanks for the comments and feedback.

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                     animations:^{ 

    controller.searchResultsTableView.frame = frogTableView.frame;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame = frogTableView.frame;

    searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(32,
                                                         55,
                                                         270,
                                                         searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height);

    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(32,
                                 55,
                                 270,
                                 searchBar.frame.size.height);
                         frogTableView.frame = CGRectMake(frogTableView.frame.origin.x, 
                                                          121, 
                                                          frogTableView.frame.size.width, 
                                                          frogTableView.frame.size.height);

                         notePad.frame = CGRectMake(notePad.frame.origin.x, 
                                                    45, 
                                                    notePad.frame.size.width, 
                                                    notePad.frame.size.height);

                         searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame = frogTableView.frame;
                      } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //whatever else you may need to do

                     }];
}
```

Comment: Ooohhh, why the blocks? That should generally be used only for things like GCD or more complex networking. You're overdoing it :P

Comment: so what should i do Galaxas0 ?

Comment: Possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield

Comment: @Galaxas0 - Blocks can be used, issue has nothing to do with blocks.

Comment: I know, but it just over-polutes the code that could be far simpler.

Comment: @rip not really dupe. The animation works in didendsearch but the animation won't work in willendsearch to resize

Comment: then it can be animation timing issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble after I started to use UISearchBar with UISearchDisplayController. The solution I came up with is to place a search bar on a view:

```
UIView * searchBarSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MENU_WORK_AREA_WIDTH, SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT)] ;
searchBarSubview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
searchBarSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UISearchBar * globalSearchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MENU_WORK_AREA_WIDTH, SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT)] autorelease];
globalSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
globalSearchBar.delegate = self;
[globalSearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage alloc]];
```

and resize the view instead of search bar in searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

// Slide in to the final destination
searchBarSubview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MENU_WORK_AREA_WIDTH, SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```