# How to override textRectForBounds and editingRectForBounds for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am using a search bar (`UISearchBar`) in my app and I want to override the `editingRectForBounds` and `textRectForBounds` method.

How would I be able to do this? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean? Just create a subclass that inherits from  UISearchBar?

Comment: @Vincent But `editingRectForBounds` and `textRectForBounds` are overriding methods for `UITextField` and not for `UISearchBar`, right? Anyways, I've tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to restrict size of text field, this could be useful  1.Create a subclass of UISearchBar
2.Include this code in the drawRect: method.

UITextView * textField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 6, (310 - kRightSideMargin), 31);

[super drawRect:rect];  [changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield)

Comment: My intention is to modify the textRect but not the size of the text field itself.   Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Create a subclass of UITextField

eg.
@interface DemoTextField : UITextField

and simply override your methods in implementation (.m) file