# Change the size of UITextField inside UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, size, uisearchbar

I want to change the width of the textfield that is inside `UISearchBar` keeping its appearance.

I've tried to subclass `UISearchBar` and in `drawRect` check the `self.subviews` that is a kind of class `UITextField` and change its width, but didn't work.

I also tried this inside the `layoutSubviews` method but keep not working.

My objective is to have a `UIButton` over the right side of `UISearchBar`, but when I'm writing text, it can't be overlap by the `UIButton`.

Comment: so you want the search bar to be wider?

Comment: this might helps you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield

Comment: Yes, my goal is to have the search bar wider than the Textfield inside of it. The link that Yuyutsu suggests does not answer to my need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use UISearchBar, try the following steps:
1. Set UISearchBar's userInteractionEnabled property to NO
2. Add a UITextField above the search bar
3. Set search bar's text property when the content of UITextField is changed.

It is not a good idea to change the textfield inside the search bar, because when a new version ios comes, the struct of UISearchBar maybe changed and your code may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

simply create custom search Bar using `UItextField` and set all properties that you want. I was did it same way, even I was tried same that you did but it didn't work.event UItextField having various event so you can implement your search functionality based on that event.